# chart_Series add_TA name

Tags: r, quantmod

Hello helpful community,

I am currently stuck with a problem around `chart_Series` and `add_TA`. I want to plot the names of the vertical line I have added next to it. The name could me above the line or left to it, but since I'm using `chart_Series` in `shiny`, I would hope for a solution where the name is still displayed after zooming in on the chart.

I tried `name` as well as `legend.name` as part of the `add_TA` function. Neither which led to a satisfying solution. The documentation on `chart_Series` in `quantmod` is not very detailed on this level. I would appreciate your help and I am thankful for any advise and hint!

The following example code should produce a similar graphical result:

```
library(quantmod)
data <- getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign = FALSE)
x_ti <- xts(rnorm(NROW(data)), order.by = index(data))
x_ti2 <- xts(rep(1, NROW(data)), order.by = index(data))
x_ti2[1, ] <- 0.5 

chart_Series(data["2017"])
add_TA(x_ti2, col = "orange", pch = 9, type = 'p', cex = .7)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. I see no vertical line produced.
Adding `name = 'TEST'` inside `add_TA` added a title to the TA. It also produced some warnings, but that's expected as this functions are still experimental. Why does that not  satisfy you? What are you trying to produce?

Comment: Hello @GGamba, thank you for your response. I am using multiple straight lines. The names are not plotet next to the correct lines and only one name is added.